# GPT to MBR: gdisk overlap

Tags: gpt, mbr

I have a 256GB NVMe SSD drive and this is other system drive, which my friend converted from MBR to GTP.

This is my output. I used gdisk to convert GPT to MBR, but I have a problem.

```
Problem: MBR partitions 1 and 2 overlap!
Warning: Deleting oversized partition #1! Start = 1920221984, length = 1816210284
Warning: Deleting oversized partition #2! Start = 1936028192, length = 1953653108
```

Device infomation: CPU i3-9100, RAM 8GB, 128GB SSD system drive, Ubuntu 20.10.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the complete output of `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdX` and `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sdX`, replace `sdX` with the device name of your drive.

Comment: You might try to repair the mbr running `testdisk` - see http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step

Comment: While you still need to resolve issue, why convert to MBR? The only place MBR is still required is for Windows in BIOS boot mode. And Microsoft has required Windows to be installed in UEFI boot mode with gpt partitioning since Windows 8 released in 2012. Linux can boot in BIOS mode with bios_grub partition or in UEFI mode with ESP - efi system partition on gpt partitioned drives.